# how to declare a vector of thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, declaration

i'm new in c++ programing and need some help to use a thread library with vector library...

first I follow this [tutorial](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/02/27/cpp-11-thread-tutorial-part-2/)

but the compiler (visual studio 2013) show me errors and I don't know how correct it:

first declaration of function

```
void Fractal::calcIterThread(vector<vector<iterc>> &matriz, int desdePos, int hastaPos, int idThread){
   ...
}
```

in main loop

```
vector<vector<iterc>> res;
res.resize(altoPantalla);

for (int i = 0; i < altoPantalla; i++){
   res[i].resize(anchoPantalla);
}

int numThreads = 10;
vector<thread> workers(numThreads);

for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++){ //here diferent try
   thread workers[i] (calcIterThread, ref(res), inicio, fin, i)); // error: expresion must have a constant value
   workers[i] = thread(calcIterThread, ref(res), inicio, fin, i)); // error: no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list
}

...rest of code...
```

thanks for any help to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

// ...

int numThreads = 10;
std::vector<std::thread> workers;

for (int i = 0; i != numThreads; ++i)
{
    workers.emplace_back(calcIterThread, std::ref(res), inicia, fin, i);
}

for (auto & t : workers)
{
    t.join(); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.... now this error apears... "error C3867: 'Fractal::calcIterThread': function call missing argument list; use '&Fractal::calcIterThread' to create a pointer to member"

Comment: Isn't the error message itself telling you EXACTLY how to fix the error?

Comment: other error appears when I correct with suggestion of compiler ... (a extract) error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 4 arguments
1>          class does not define an 'operator()' or a user defined conversion operator to a pointer-to-function or reference-to-function that takes appropriate number of arguments
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(1137) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Bind<true,void,std::_Pmf_wrap<void (__thiscall Fractal::* )(std::vector<std::vector<iterc,std .......

Answer (score 1):

finally I can solve the problem with this change in my code...

```
workers.emplace_back(thread{ [&]() {
    calcIterThread(ref(res), inicio, fin, i);
}});
```